# How to use dockerhub-notification-plugin in Jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, dockerhub

I want to trigger a pipeline when a new image is pushed to docker hub.
I installed [dockerhub-notification-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/dockerhub-notification-plugin). 
If I use web UI it's possible to specify the docker hub repo:

[image]

I tried to use pipeline snippet generator, but it is not working correctly: if I specify a repo it's ignored in generated code. 
For example:

[image]

generates code:

```
properties([pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'DockerHubTrigger', options: []]])])
```

As you can see there is no docker hub repo specified in the generated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to write your properties like below:

```
properties([
    pipelineTriggers([[$class: 'DockerHubTrigger', options: [[$class: 'TriggerOnSpecifiedImageNames', repoNames: ["YOUR_REPO_NAME"].toSet()]]]])
])
```

First notice the additional parenthesis around options value. This is due to the way how groovy scripts are evaluated in jenkins.

But why set?

According to the [javadoc](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/dockerhub-notification/org/jenkinsci/plugins/registry/notification/opt/impl/TriggerOnSpecifiedImageNames.html) `TriggerOnSpecifiedImageNames` class has three constructors: without parameters, with varargs of strings and with collection. But groovy will use reflection to instantiate this class, which means that the default constructor will be called and later respective properties will be applied. And this brings us to the `toSet()` because as you can see in javadoc there is a setter for repo names property which looks like follow: `setRepoNames(Set<String> repoNames)`.